# Can I use the undocumented method pathlib.Path.absolute()?

Tags: python, pathlib

The first method found by auto-complete on a `pathlib.Path` is `absolute()`.

It seems to just prepend [Path.cwd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.cwd) at the start:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path('./relative/path') / '../with/some/../relative/parts'
Path('relative/path/../with/some/../relative/parts')
# calling absolute...
>>> absolute_path = path.absolute()
Path('/[current_dir]/relative/path/../with/some/../relative/parts')
# does the same as prepending cwd at the start
>>> Path.cwd() / path
Path('/[current_dir]/relative/path/../with/some/../relative/parts')
```

However, `Path.absolute()` is not listed in the [pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.cwd).

Compare this to [Path.resolve()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve), which does the opposite (replace relative parts but don't prepend `cwd`) and  *is* documented.

Can I use `absolute()` or should I avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

No.

At least up until Python version 3.8, you should avoid using `Path.absolute()`.

According to the discussion in [the bug report about the missing documentation](https://bugs.python.org/issue29688),
`absolute()` is not tested, and therefore not officially advertised.  In fact, it *might* even be removed in a future release of Python.

So it's safer to just use `Path.cwd()` instead.

```py
>>> # make path absolute if it isn't already
>>> path = Path.cwd() / path
Path('/[current_dir]/relative/path/../with/some/../relative/parts')
```

It's not necessary to check beforehand using [Path.is_absolute()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.is_absolute) since `cwd() / path` will not change a path that's already absolute.